# Prolog : backtrack more than one step backwards (backjumping!)?

Tags: prolog, backtracking, skip

This may be simple question, but here goes ..... let say I have something along the lines :

```
.... step1, step2, step3, ...
```

i want every time step3 fail backtracking to skip step2 and go to step1 instead, but on the way forward to follow the normal ..step1, step2, step3 .. sequence.

```
.... step1, (step2, step3), ...
```

doesn't seem to do it, or I'm doing something wrong.

---

It needs more testing, but this seems to work so far :

```
.... step1, (step2 -> (step3; true)), ...
```

may be this is swi-prolog idiosyncrasy, to require true.

Comment: Possibly `step1, (step2 -> step3)` but I only did a superficial test. Not sure why you would want this. It means that you would only ever get the first solution out of `step2`. So I think it's the same as `step1, once(step2), step3` (if  your Prolog has the `once/1` predicate).

Answer (score 3):

In the literature, this search strategy is also called **backjumping**.

One way to implement this in Prolog is using **exceptions**.

See the ISO predicates `catch/3` and `throw/1`:

In particular, in your case, you could arrange it so that failure of `step3` leads to a "ball" being thrown via `throw/1`, which can be caught via `catch/3` at the intended target position.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `step1, (step2, step3)` is no different in behavior than `step1, step2, step3`. The parentheses only force a precedence grouping, which has no effect in this case (it's like writing `1 + (2 + 3)` instead of `1 + 2 + 3`).

A possible solution is:

```
step1, (step2 -> step3)
```

It means that you would only ever get the first solution out of `step2`. So I think it's the same as:

```
step1, once(step2), step3
```

A "step" in the above two examples could be a conjunction of sub-steps, with suitable parentheses, if desired.